# sed append a text with many lines after matching of multiple strings while the text remains many lines in sed command

Tags: sed

**In the question:**
[sed append after a line containing multiple unordered strings](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/320475/sed-append-after-a-line-containing-multiple-unordered-strings)

Now I'm running sed inside script to append a large text. But how to not concatenating strings in one sed command. That is to say for example, I want to insert the following text:

```
firstline
secondline
thirdline
fourthline
```

And in sed, I want to write something like the following in a **script** file:

```
sed -i '/Hello World/a \\
firstline\\
secondline\\
thirdline\\
fourthline' file
```

Instead, now i'm matching many unordered strings.

Dont know how and where to break like this after requiring matching multiple strings. The \\ is definitely nicer and easy to modify especially if there are large numbers of appended lines.

Comment: Would you satisfy with `sed -i '/Hello/!b; /Word/a \ …`